# React Router no me posiciona al inicio de la pagina

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Buenos dìas estoy usando React Router por primera vez, el caso es que es una aplicaciòn landing page con 5 pestañas o rutas,

El error que presento es que cuando estoy por ejemplo en Home y bajo hasta el footer, y luego selecciono  para ir a otra pagina, al cambiar de pagina no me posiciona al principio de esta si no que me deja ahì mismo en el footer.

¿Existe alguna manera de detectar el cambio de ruta para poder llevar el scroll hasta arriba cada vez que se cambie de pagina?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No tengo claro como es tu diseño, pero donde tengas tus rutas puedes verificar el cambio de ubicación en un `useLayoutEffect` en el `wrapper` que esta envolviendo tus rutas. Si existe un cambio, se desplazara hasta la parte superior. Aquí hay un ejemplo de como sería.

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import HouseContextProvider from "./Context/HouseContext";

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location.pathname]);
  return children;
};
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <HouseContextProvider>
    <Router>
      <Wrapper>
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<App />} />
          </Routes>
        </React.StrictMode>
      </Wrapper>
    </Router>
  </HouseContextProvider>
);
```